# It's like Cheating Men must die but MC is a male

Tags: story-identification, manga

What is the title of this kind of manwha, manhua or manga, idk which. He is a successful man who uses women as sexual tools. After that he got killed by one of the women he played and died. After that he obtained a system which is like the cheating men must die reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be *[Supporting Actor's Survival Game](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/supporting-actors-survival-game)*?

> Experiencing an unexpected death, Qi Yan was forced to bind a fast time travel system which enables him to time travel across various different worlds to win the targets' hearts. For Qi Yan, this is just a task that has to be accomplished. It is just a game that does not involve emotion and feelings. He is confident that he can withdraw unscathed and unemotional. But the experience in every task is so real, even if he tells himself over and over that it's all illusions, he still can't completely isolate himself from those feelings...

Found on [this list](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/cheating-men-must-die/recommendations) found by searching for `isekai cheats "must die"`